# access oracle web interface (Oracle 12 c)

Tags: oracle12c

I installed Oracle 12 c Server Class on my windows machine.It installed successfully.Now,if I want to access the web interface,how can I find which port to use in url? 
I understand we use this url:
https://hostname:portnumber/em

so,what would be the hostname also and what is "em"? Is it "em" in all cases?

Comment: Probably  `https://localhost:1158/em` EM stands for enterprise manager

Comment: no,this did not help.says "unable to connect"

Comment: got it working..u need the port number from your sql command like first and use this url to access the Web UI